# Serve APT repo with Aptly + Github Pages

Tags: github-pages, apt

I have created one APT repo using [aptly](https://www.aptly.info/)

The repo works well on my local.
But I want to host this APT repo via Github Pages

Say, My github repo is [abc.xyz.io](https://abc.xyz.io) which is also my domain name
My apt content is at abc.xyz.io/apt-repo

How do I setup my aptly.conf accordingly ?

Can [FileSystemPublishEndpoints](https://www.aptly.info/doc/feature/filesystem/) help ?